# How to write a switch statement with do-syntax?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

Syntactically, how can I write a switch statement using [do expressions](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-do-expressions/)?

e.g. this:

```
<div>
{do{
    switch(foo) {
      case 'a':
          <Bar/>
        case 'b':
          <Baz/>
    }
}}
</div>
```

comes out as

```
'use strict';

React.createElement(
  'div',
  null,
  function () {
    switch (foo) {
      case 'a':
        React.createElement(Bar, null);
      case 'b':
        React.createElement(Baz, null);
    }
  }()
);
```

[REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=env%2Creact%2Cstage-0&targets=Node-8&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&experimental=true&loose=true&spec=false&code=%3Cdiv%3E%0A%7Bdo%7B%0A%20%20%20%20switch(foo)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20'a'%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CBar%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20'b'%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CBaz%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%7D%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E)

Note the lack of `return`s in the output -- i.e., it's useless. Babel won't let me add returns to the source though. Is it even possible to use `switch`es inside of a `do` exppression?

Comment: This looks like a bug in Babel.

Comment: What do you expect to be returned? Returned from where? To what? What is the actual problem you want to solve?

Comment: `switch` doesn't return a value, so there is nothing for `do` to return. It looks like you're trying to use `switch` similarly to a ternary operator, but it doesn't work that way.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude If it's not apparent, I want the entire do expression evaluate to either `<Bar/>` or `<Baz/>`.

Comment: @sbking `if` doesn't return anything either. I was hoping for some do-magic. The entire thing is just syntax sugar to make writing JSX a little easier. Maybe it doesn't work that way though.

Comment: @mpen Yeah `if` doesn't return anything, but you don't need an `if` statement to use a ternary operator. For example: `<div>{foo === 'a' ? <Bar /> : <Baz />}</div>`

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work probably because `switch` is not an expression (but neither is `if`, so I don't know, it might be just a bug in Babel). A workaround for this is to assign the value to some variable and place it at the and of the `do` block (remember to add `break`s too):

```
<div>
{do{
    let r;
    switch(foo) {
      case 'a':
          r = <Bar/>
          break;
        case 'b':
          r = <Baz/>
          break;
    }
    r;
}}
</div>
```

Comment: also don't forget the `break` lines!